# Yii CMultiFileUpload select multiple files at once doesnt work

Tags: yii, multiple-select, cmultifileupload

i want to select multiple files at once, but only ONE File always shows up in the MultiFile-list Div container with the possibility to delete it. But i want to shop up all the files i selected.
What am i doing wrong?

```
$this->widget('CMultiFileUpload', array(
'model' => $gallery,
'name' => 'attachments',
'accept' => 'jpg|png',
'denied' => 'Only doc,docx,pdf and txt are allowed',
'max' => 100,
'duplicate' => 'Already Selected',
'options'=>array(

 ),
'htmlOptions' => array('multiple' => 'multiple', 'size' => 25)
    )
```

);

Answer (score 1):

CMultiFileUpload is based on [jQuery Multiple File Upload Plugin ($.MultiFile)](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/) . On it's site we can read:

> What this isn't
>
> This plugin will not create a dialog that allows the user to select multiple files at once. That simply cannot be done via javascript. If that's what you need, you should consider using HTML5's multiple="multiple" attribute or one of the many other flash based file upload solutions (eg.: SWFupload, uploadify and others)

So probably the built in widget isn't what you are looking for. [Xupload yii extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/xupload/), on the other hand might be what you are looking for.